# Java 8 ToLongFunction when should I use it?

Tags: java, java-8

Java 8 now has functional interfaces, such as ToLongFunction which converts its parameter to a long value.

I saw an example as the code below:

```
ToLongFunction<String> i  = (x)-> Long.parseLong(x);

System.out.println(i.applyAsLong("2"));
```

**The question is**: Why should I implement an interface just to convert a variable to a primitive long, where it would be more simple and readable to just call the method Long.parseLong(x)?

Comment: It's used to represent an anonymous function. If you have a higher order function that takes a function that must return a long after converting it's parameter, you set the type of the passed function to `ToLongFunction`.

Comment: Don't. It leads to NPEs as soon as any value is null because Java cannot auto-unbox null values. It's using a primitve type instead of Long.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is that you *wouldn't* do that at all, you'd just call `Long.parseLong()` directly in that case.

The longer answer point is that you rarely explicitly declare explicit variables of the type `ToLongFunction` as you did with your `i` above, but rather indirectly use the functional interface as a target when writing a lambda for one of the many functions that take them.

To use an example from the new `Stream` interface, you may want to take a `List<String> input` of `String` objects that have numerical values like: `["123", "456", ...]` and parse them all into a list of `long`.

You can do that with something like:

```
long[] result = input.stream().mapToLong( x -> Long.parseLong(x) ).toArray();
```

Here you never wrote `ToLongFunction` directly, but indirectly used it by providing a lambda method to `mapToLong(ToLongFunction f)`, which calls your `Long.parseLong(x)` method. So the functional interface was the magic that helped make that work.

So you'll make indirect use of this interface all the time with `Stream` and other lambda related features in Java 8, but you may not use it explicitly very often (unless you are writing classes which want to *accept* such a function).

Comment: In the first sentence I think you meant parseLong instead of parseInt

Answer (score 5):

> Java 8 now has functional interfaces, such as ToLongFunction which converts its parameter to a long value.

This is a misunderstanding of `ToLongFunction`: it's intended to be *any* function that has a primitive long output, whether that's gotten through `Long.parseLong` or some other completely different function; maybe it's `Person.getIdNumber()`.

In any event, you should essentially never reference `ToLongFunction` except when you're writing a method that *accepts* a lambda that you want to have a primitive `long` result.  Otherwise, just write the lambda directly.